# SWT: widths of toolbar items

Tags: swt, toolbar

We are using toolbar items with text below. Especially for short texts, this looks quite odd, because the toolbar items are much narrower than high. Is there a way to tell SWT to increase the toolbar items widths, e.g., to a minimum size which is as wide as the buttons are high?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean text below? Is the text inside the items? Then they should behave in a .pack() manner. You can't really change the width of the items (only separators) but have you tried adding spaces or tabs to the text? And if there is an image you can just edit the images to be the width you want...

Comment: I set both, the image and the text. At least on Windows the text occurs below the image. Of course I could change the image width, but IMHO this would be a bad option.

Comment: There has *got* to be a better way to do this.  Surely this is a pretty common problem.